# surviving ios memory warning

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tutorial app that demonstrates how to use `UINavigationController`. Mostly app works right.

When I simulate memory warning it losts some data. I have two `UIViewController` in an `UINavigationController`. There is an `UIButton` on first `UIViewController`'s view and when user touches that `UIButton`, second `UIViewController` is created and pushed navigation stack by first `UIViewController`. I pass data from second `UIViewController` to first `UIViewController` via `NSNotificationCenter`.

With this approach the app works fine, but if I simulate memory warning when second `UIViewController`'s view is visible nothing passes back. So how can I survive in that case.

Comment: Can we see the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

When a memory warning is triggered, the app tries to get rid of all the objects that are not needed anymore. This probably removes the listener from the first UIViewController.

The problem with NSNotificationCenter is that there is not an easy way to check if the listeners are active or not.

I don't know if this situation is suited for using the NSNotification setup. It's easy to lose control of what messages are sent to what viewcontroller.

Maybe this setup is easier (and probably memory safer). It keeps a reference to the first UIViewController object

```
//
//  SecondViewController.h
//  test
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) ViewController *parentViewController;

@end
```

and the .m file

```
//
//  SecondViewController.m
//  test
//
//

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize parentViewController;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    parentViewController.yourObject = @"your value";
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [parentViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When pushing the second viewcontroller do this:

```
SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.parentViewController = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think keeping view controllers seperate (allowing them not to talk each other directly) is better design. I think I'm gonna create seperate model class that keeps data changes.